# PHP adds double backslash when $_POST['myjsonitem'], causing json_decode result in JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

Tags: php, json

Cant' believe it, millions of posts covering this topic but I can't get it to work.

In my Android App I am sending a volley POST request to the server. This request is a normal StringRequest and it contains a serialized json object.

On the server, the item in the POST request arrives like this, I extracted the raw body data via

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

=>

```
myjsonitem=%5B%7B%22description%22%3A%22Back%22%2C%22freeText%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isRated%22%3Atrue%2C%22priceSingle%22%3A12.0%2C%22ratingStar%22%3A4.0%7D%2C%7B%22description%22%3A%22SoronA%22%2C%22freeText%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isRated%22%3Atrue%2C%22priceSingle%22%3A3.5%2C%22ratingStar%22%3A5.0%7D%5D
```

As you can see, the item arrives with double quotes around the respective json elements, for me this seems correct so far.

The problem starts when I want to json_decode the string, via:

```
$itemList = json_decode($_POST['myjsonitem'], true);
```

This command returns a json_decode error JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.
I could not understand why, so I wrote the json to the log via:

```
error_log("Json String: " .$_POST['myjsonitem']);
```

The result in the log shows:

```
Json String: [{\\"description\\":\\"Back\\",\\"freeText\\":\\"\\",\\"isRated\\":true,\\"priceSingle\\":12.0,\\"ratingStar\\":4.0},{\\"description\\":\\"SoronA\\",\\"freeText\\":\\"\\",\\"isRated\\":true,\\"priceSingle\\":3.5,\\"ratingStar\\":4.0}]
```

As you can see, double Backslashes were added infront of the double quotes. Putting this string into a JSON Validator returns an invalid json. Removing the doulbe backslashes returns a valid json.

Magic Quotes can't be the problem because I am running php 7+.

What is going on here? How can I parse correctly the PHP? Just simply removing the double backslashes will not help I guess, in my freeText field I could have strings with double quotes, so the escaping should still work in that cases.

**EDIT**: Here is the crucial part with context. Maybe I should mention that I run this on a wordpress installation and at the beginning of my php file, i include wp-load.php.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //getting some other data from request  
    $dateString = $_POST['date'];   
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateString));        
    $userId = intval($_POST['userId']); 
    $sentUniqueId = $_POST['uniqueId']; 

    //crucial part goes here:   
    $itemsList = json_decode($_POST['myjsonitem'], true);   

    //output 
    error_log("Json String: " .$itemsList);
```

The output I posted (the one with the double backslashes) is in my error_log file.

Comment: I think your double backslash some how are a false positive, I don't see those when I `urldecode` your string.

Comment: Iäm a bit confused, do you use `file_get_contents('php://input')` for reading the raw data, then use `$_POST` to read the data later anyway? Or was `file_get_contents('php://input')` just for showing the raw input you get?

Comment: @Johan  file_get_contents was used to analyze/debug what actually comes in the Body because I was deperate. I dont use the $entityBody object any further. Instead, like posted, I use $_POST['myjsonitem'] to get the content..I will edit my post with a bit more information.

Comment: @Scuzzy the url decoded string is null in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Most important thing: I tried to run this php code in a **Wordpress** context. 
[Deep down in the Wordpress function reference I found this:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep)

> WordPress adds slashes to $_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST/$_COOKIE regardless of what get_magic_quotes_gpc() returns. So in the context of WordPress, stripslashes() or stipslashes_deep() should always be used when using those variables.

Ok so the solution was easy now:

```
$my_value = stripslashes($_POST['myjsonitem']); 
$itemsList = json_decode($my_value, true);
```

It removes the slashes escaping the double quotes of the json elements, but DID NOT remove the slashes in the respective text strings, which was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your original response is URL Enoded. You need to pass it into `urldecode` before decoding it with `json_decode`:

```
$json = urldecode($_POST['myjsonitem']);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: I parsed the raw body data of the request via $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); and posted the result. Anyway I tried your suggestion, it didn't work. I will edit my post anyway, thank you for your input.

Comment: Yes thats strange, urldecode returns null in my case